# Calling table name IN parameter for procedure and outputting every column name in that table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Sorry if this is not a good question, I feel like it should be simple but I'm not getting the result I want :(

I created the a stored procedure that prints out all of my table names in `USER_TABLES`. Now what I want to do now is call another procedure within the first procedure to output all of the columns in my tables.

What I have:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ColumnNames(

newColumn.Table_Name IN varchar2
)
AS
  CURSOR newColumn IS
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM USER_TABLES;
  CurrentRow newColumn%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR CurrentRow IN newColumn LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CurrentRow.Column_Name);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Edited to add error message:

> Error(3,10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:
> in out      ... long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the problem ? Could you add your complete code and issue what your facing exactly ?

Comment: `user_tables` is a view for tables, it doesn't contain columns. Use `user_tab_columns` for columns

Comment: this is my complete code. Just trying to make a new procedure to output column names - tables and columns are already created. I added the error to my question.

Comment: `newColumn.Table_Name IN varchar2` is not valid syntax for declaring a PL/SQL parameter. You just need to give it a proper name, like `p_table_name`. Although, as your procedure doesn't actually use the parameter, you should just remove the entire declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Use `user_tab_columns` instead of `user_tables`.
Variable `newColumn.Table_Name` does nothing in your code and has incorrect name(contains dot symbol)
Also cursor and variable declaration are excessive in current case.
If you need to print all column names for particular table you can use

```
create or replace procedure print_columns(tab_name in varchar2) is
begin
    for col in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = tab_name) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(col.column_name);
    end loop;
end;
/
```